# Vim execute code on remapping in vimrc

Tags: vim

I have created the following mapping in my **vimrc** file:

```
noremap <C-p> ! firefox -new-tab http://php.net/<cword><C-m>
```

The problem is that it proceeds to **delete the line** under the cursor.

How would I make this mapping work correctly?

Comment: Maybe you should rather remap `K` for this and only for buffers with `filetype` set to `php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do the following should work:

```
nmap <c-p> :!firefox  -new-tab http://php.net/<c-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>
```

See [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_=) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `noremap` which means that it triggers:

- in normal mode
- in visual mode
- in operator-pending mode.

You should use `nnoremap` or `xnoremap` instead. Also, note that `!` is a shortcut for `:.!` in normal mode (acts on current line) and for `:'<,'>!` in visual mode (acts on current visually-selected lines). If you don't want that:

```
nnoremap <c-p> :!firefox ... 
xnoremap <c-p> :<c-u>!firefox ...
```